# Adding excel XY data to Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, clustering, xy

I am having some issues with adding xy data from a .csv file. As you can see in the picture below the points are clustering. I am not sure if this is a excel format issue or a arcmap issue.

I am simply adding the .csv to arcmap> display xy data> no z field and coordinate system of: Geographic Coordinate System: Name: GCS_WGS_1984

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your CSV file?

Comment: Can you include in your question how you are creating the point layer from .csv?

Comment: have you tried zooming in?

Comment: Added the CSV file SS

Comment: How many records are in the excel sheet?  What happens if you copy maybe 50% of the records into another excel sheet and try that one?

Comment: I feel like posting this on my door to see if anyone else (besides my teammates who needed a hint) can figure it out!

Answer (score 5):

I am not seeing any decimal values greater than .59 nor .xx59 in your Excel spreadsheet. I think the spreadsheet has DD.MMmmm (degree-decimal minutes) or DD.MMSSssss (degree-minute-decimal seconds) values, not decimal degrees, DD.ddddddd. Take a look at the spreadsheet to see if you seen any .xxxx values that have >59 in the 3rd and 4th positions. If you can identify any, you have DD.MMmmmmm data.

ArcToolbox/Geoprocessing has a tool, Convert Coordinate Notation, which should be able to convert these values to decimal degrees before you attempt to add them as XY data.